# msie issue with JS Hashchange Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to load my wordpress based website with AJAX following this [Tutorial](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme.html). All of the code makes sence to me but they are using a plugin called [JS Hashchange Event](https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/v1.3/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js). The issue I am having is that in part it uses the `$.browser.msie` so when I run it with jQuery 1.9 I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined` error. I tried adding the js migrate plugin but it did not work. I read that I could add this bit of code

```
jQuery.browser={};(function(){jQuery.browser.msie=false;
jQuery.browser.version=0;if(navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)){
jQuery.browser.msie=true;jQuery.browser.version=RegExp.$1;}})();
```

but not sure where to put it. Anyone had this issue? Or maybe a better way to use AJAX with loading wordpress pages (keep the header and footer static)?

Answer (score 16):

The `$.browser` has been removed as of jQuery 1.9.

Straight from the docs: [$.browser](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

> The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and
>   is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin. We recommend using feature detection with a library
>   such as Modernizr.

You can use the [jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) plugin to restore removed functionality if needed. If it didn't work, you can try using [Ben Alman's hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/), and replace `$.browser.msie` with `(document.documentMode != undefined)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update of this script, Please refer the URL : https://github.com/georgekosmidis/jquery-hashchange

2013-29-11 fix: As of jQuery 1.9 $.browser used in Ben's code isn't supported anymore.